# Error for this code : TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python

```py
studentList= list()
courseList = list()
class Student:      
    def StudentInfo():
        
        NumberOfStudent = int(input("How many students in this class?"))
        for i in range (NumberOfStudent):
                print("student no "+ " ", i+1)
                id = input ("id:")
                name = input ("name:")
                DoB = input ("Date of birth: ")

                student = {
                    "id" : id ,
                    "name" : name,
                    "DoB" : DoB
                }
                studentList.append(student)
 def ListStudent():
        NumberOfStudent = len(studentList)
        for i in range (NumberOfStudent):
            print ("No" + i+1 +":" + studentList[i] ) 
        return
StudentInfo()
ListStudent()
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following line of code, you are trying to concatenate `str` ("No" and ":") with `int` (i+1).

```
print ("No" + i+1 +":" + studentList[i] )
```

You should convert the no-str datas to `str` like this:

```
print ("No" + str(i+1) +":" + str(studentList[i]))
```

Another solution is to use f-string like this (put `f` before your string and your variables between `{.}`):

```
print (f"No{i+1}:{studentList[i]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you can't concatenate a string and an integer. You can resolve this by turning the integer into a string via `int_as_str = str(i+1)` and then using the variable `int_as_str` (with a better name).

A more general thing you should do here, though, is use f-strings for formatting strings like this. For example, you should use `print(f"No {i+1}: {studentList[i]}"`. Putting the `f` at the beginning of the string allows you to call variables directly inside the {}.